# How to show the execution plan of a statement with Sequelize.js

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm building my app with express and using postgresql as database, sequelize.js as ORM.

I was wondering how I can use `EXPLAIN` in sequelize, to get the execution plan. On Mongodb for example it is done with `.explain()` ([postgresql website](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) , [mongodb example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)).

I'm looking for the equivalent in sequelize but can't find it. My query looks like this:

```
User.findOne({
  where: { id: req.params.id },
  include: {
    model: Post
  }
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this feature does not exist, though it would be a good one. To accomplish this, you can output Sql logs to the console and then paste those into your Postgres CLI with `explain`

Answer (score 2):

I made a raw query, `sequelize.query('EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM users', {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})` and got my results.